# What is the name for "section topics" printed in the margins

Tags: publications, citations, terminology, formatting

In older publications of many languages, there are frequently printed text in the margins that detail the topic of a section of the text (see below on the left and right):

Excerpt from *Magnum Oecumenicum Constantiense Concilium*:
[image: Excerpt from Magnum oecumenicum Constantiense Concilium]

What is the name for these? I considered marginalia, but they are not handwritten.

Comment: Why can't marginalia be typed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although many marginal notes are made by hand, the term marginalia is also often used for [printed ones](https://www.earlyprintedbooks.com/feature/printed-marginalia/). There is even a [book about "printed marginalia"](https://books.google.com/books?id=en34I1tTzHwC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). A definition of marginalia given [here](http://www.usask.ca/english/architectures/pages2/contents/marginalia.html) states

> The term "marginalia" generally refers to handwritten or printed text situated at the borders of the page.

Depending on the textual content, words like [gloss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloss_(annotation)), [annotation or side note](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/459939/315609) can also apply (although the latter also has a more metaphorical meaning).